# How to run javascript code from string in safe way

Tags: javascript

I found some answers, but very old one and I wondered how can it be done?

I've seen that `eval()` function isn't safe:

[Alternate for eval() to execute auto-generated JS code from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982556/alternate-for-eval-to-execute-auto-generated-js-code-from-the-server)

So what are my options in order to run a javascript code in isolated secured way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string look at here

Comment: If it was totally isolated, you wouldn't need to run it. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Bergi I want to build an app that allow you to share code and execute it.

Comment: @Dorki Users running code that is shared by other users is inherently unsafe. Don't do that. If you take a look at how all the code sharing platforms work (including things like StackSnippets): they serve the code on a separate domain and sandbox it in an iframe protected by the SOP.

Comment: Why not load external JS files with xmlhttprequest? You should also have some sort of backend filter that makes sure no unsafe functions or libraries are used.

Comment: @Bergi stackoverflow's website has the feature to execute javascript code, maybe something related to iframe or isolated environment?

Comment: @hewiefreeman Is there a well-known library that does that already?

Comment: @Dorki Ah, I was still editing my comment :-) Yes, they use iframes. They do not "run code from a string".

Comment: @Bergi ohhh, that's a bit cleared some fuzzy about how it works, so the question is whether using the same domain could also be secured? I mean, I could make my backend to send the string ( that should be convereted to code ) to an new url, but couldn't it be bypass or hacked with any js code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10653809/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/22506026/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/195149/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/2986908/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/5044608/1048572

Answer (score -1):

(as pointed out, this answer is outdated and the proposed solution could be easily broken).

Currently, draft for [secure ecmascript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-ses) has not been approved/implemented yet.
One hack that has decent browser support (proxy is es6 feature) is using `proxies` and `with` to create a sandbox.

You just have to write a proxy which returns null for every requested key except for some safe functions.
`with` would ask the proxy every time a var outside eval is required (for example, window) and so, provide null instead of the real var.

Check this website for a tutorial:
[code sandbox](https://blog.risingstack.com/writing-a-javascript-framework-sandboxed-code-evaluation/)

Comment: **No.** This doesn't provide real safety.

Comment: why? I could not find an example that breaks it - moreover I've seen it used in a commercial solution by a big tech company. Of course, it's an hack - not a true solution (iframes are too).

Comment: You can get access to the main window object with `this`.

Comment: no, you can bind "this" to another var (JavaScript perfectly allows it).

Comment: No, `this` is a reserved word. You can't name a variable after it.

Comment: Try to "sandbox" this code with that technique and see what happens: `new (()=>{}).constructor("this.alert('oops')")()`. By the way, I feel bad for that "big tech company".

Comment: wow, you're right. I've never thought about it. I'll edit the answer immediately. please add a comment to the tutorial too - I know it's widely used.